# Product of projection operators

Tags: hilbert-spaces, projection

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, let $E$ and $F$ be closed subspaces of $H$, and let $P: H \to E$ and $Q: H \to F$ be projection operators. Prove that $PQ$ is a projection operator if and only if $[E \ominus (E \cap F)] \perp [F \ominus (E \cap F)]$.

Here $E \ominus (E \cap F) = E \cap (E \cap F)^\perp$ and $F \ominus (E \cap F) = F \cap (E \cap F)^\perp$.

My attempt:
I consider using the proposition that $PQ$ is a projection operator if and only if $PQ=QP$.

($\Leftarrow$) Let $x \in H$. I want to show that $PQx = QPx$.

Write $x = Px + x'$ and $x = Qx + x''$, where $x' \perp E$ and $x'' \perp F$.

Then $Qx = QPx + Qx'$ and $Px = PQx + Px''$.

Then $PQx = PQPx + PQx' = QPx + PQx'$ since $QPx \in E$, and similarly $QPx = QPQx + QPx'' = PQx + QPx''$.

Thus, $(PQ - QP)x = PQx' = -QPx''$.

Then I want to use the given condition to deduce that $PQx' = -QPx'' = 0$, but I'm stuck.

I have solved the other direction.

Any comments or hints are appreciated.